# Combine rows based on min date and max date in a SQL query

Tags: sql

What I am looking to accomplish is to consolidate rows into one row per barcode based off of the min date and the max date. An example is:

```
ClientNumber       On Date         Off Date        Barcode
------------------------------------------------------------
1234               01/01/2018      01/30/2018      80000258
1234               01/30/2018      02/29/2018      80000258
1234               02/29/2018      03/06/2018      80000258
```

I need the result to be like this:

```
ClientNumber       On Date         Off Date        Barcode
-----------------------------------------------------------
1234               01/01/2018      03/06/2018      80000258
```

What I currently have:

```
SELECT 
    ClientNumber, 
    MIN(DateOn) AS "Min Date",  
    MAX(DateOff) AS "Max Date", 
    Barcode
FROM 
    Orders
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just missed  the `group by` clause:

```
select ClientNumber, MIN(DateOn) AS "On Date", Max(DateOff) AS "Off Date", Barcode
from Orders o
group by ClientNumber, Barcode;
```